# sequelize 4 association with hapijs, not able to make it to work

Tags: node.js, orm, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I am trying to create an association in sequelize 4, table is getting created but the foreign key reference is not happening.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/db.js");
const ValidationList = require("./validation_list.js");

const AppList = db.define("app_list", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    application: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    environment: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    instance_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    url: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

AppList.associate = function (models) {
    AppList.belongsTo(models.ValidationList, {
        foreignKey: 'application',
        targetKey: 'application_name'
    });
};

module.exports = AppList;
```

Is it something am doing wrong here?

model validation_list.js is also similar to app_list.js

```
const db = require("../config/db.js");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const ValidationList = db.define("validation_list", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    os: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    caac_folder_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    application_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    }
});

module.exports = ValidationList;
```

Here is the validation_list model.

Comment: Show validation list modal also

Comment: added validation_list model also